# Black and white colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I usually use the "seismic" colorbar of matplotlib.

For a publication need, I have to use black and white colors. I would like to keep the same aspect as "seismic" (i.e., blackest values for highest min and max values), as shown on the picture:

[image]

How do I make this conversion?

Comment: Just my opinion, but if the seismic will be in greyscale, then it's best not to use a diverging colourbar — because your readers then can't see the difference between positive and negative amplitudes.

Comment: Do you see other possibility ? I agree that we can't see the differences, but  I have to use black and white colors and I have positive and negative values...

Comment: Use a simple greyscale ramp (white for negative is conventional).

Comment: Either that or represent your data in some other way. Contour plots often look better in black and white. You could also use a 3D wireframe surface plot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my view, the best idea is to use a grey ramp instead of a diverging colourbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = 2 * np.random.random((100, 100)) - 1

plt.imshow(data, cmap='Greys', interpolation='none')
```

[image: Example of greyscale colourbar]

You can use `gray` as well, but it's just a reversed version and will give you white for positive values, which is not conventional for seismic data.

If you're set on doing what you ask, I think the easiest way might be to use `PIL` to convert images to greyscale.

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap='jet', interpolation='none')
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

Now convert it and save:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.png')
im = im.convert('L')
im.save('image_grey.png')
```